# Are Cheats in GTA5 official feature or is it some hack spread by developers/users?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

When you press ` (backtick) key in GTA5, you can enter cheat codes like `BUZZOFF`.

Now I was wondering is this official feature? I find it a bit strange because on GTA5 [official site](https://www.rockstargames.com/V/) and in their Manual, it isn't mentioned anywhere.

So is it official feature or some kind of hack which you enable by installing another *Cheat* software?

Comment: As an aside to the excellent answers, "cheat codes" are a common marketing commodity for video games. People become active in forums and discussion sharing discovered codes. Players will play a game again just to try out the cheat code. As a marketer myself (for another industry), I'd be shocked if developers didn't periodically "leak" a cheat code to keep interest in their game high while developing the fan base. Cheat codes are very much an intentional aspect of the game. Maybe back in the very beginning (70s-80s) they weren't meant for users to discover… but today they're part of the game.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are known as console commands and are pretty universal in video games. These allow developers to troubleshoot their game without necessarily quitting the game and going into their source code.

In GTA5 specifically these console commands have actually been made pretty limited. They  only allow the player to spawn items and change minor gameplay attributes. During development it would have allowed the user to teleport anywhere, load anything, or change other important features of gameplay.

Before release the usage of the console must have been restricted to spawning a limited number of items, and disabled entirely in GTA: Online.

While these are cheats, it is not implemented by a third party hacker.

Comment: Okay. Is there any official website by this game developer where I can find these cheats?

Comment: First result for “GTA5 Console Commands”

https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/gta-5-cheats-all-console-commands

Comment: of course  but I mean how would they find these cheat codes? Because they have contact with developers of GTA5?

Comment: It varies by game - Fallout has extensive documentation on Commands. GTA does not - these were either guessed, learned from decompile source code, or specifically given to game media outlets

Comment: well makes sense. So ideally I should play without cheat codes because it isn't "official" way to play GTA5 right?

Comment: Correct. It may also invalidate achievements for that save profile

Comment: If only Up Up Down Down Left Right Left Right B A were a "console command".

Comment: It's good to know that many (if not all) the GTA games have always featured cheat codes to tweak the game in many ways. For GTA VC specifically, you would lose 1000 points for each code you use.

Comment: @iBug IIRC the Konami code was originally used to trigger the devs' debug mode, so it's something similar.

Answer (score 2):

The cheats are included by the developers themselves. The cheats work on all versions of GTA 5, including consoles.

The Grand Theft Auto series has a long history of cheat codes being included in the games by the developers, and in fact, one former Rockstar Games developer [just shared](https://www.gtaboom.com/the-reason-why-there-are-two-different-codes-for-each-cheat-in-gta-san-andreas/) why and how they are implemented (which is via hashed key press recording).

The cheats are included by the developers for testing purposes and then pared back before the release of the game. In the case of GTA, some cheats are also included purely for entertainment purposes.

However, there are no cheats in GTA Online. Any cheats you see advertised for that game are either fake or hacks that will get you banned.

GTA BOOM has the complete collection of [GTA 5 cheats for all platforms](https://www.gtaboom.com/cheats/gta-5/).